# Где происходит подключение к БД

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server

В приложение добавляю подключение к MS SQL через "Источник данных". Запускаю приложение и оно показывает данные из базы.
 А где сам код подключения? Он же где-то прописывается? Хочу обработать ошибки подключения, а не могу найти где это сделать.

Comment: Где исключение сыплется, там и обрабатывайте.

Comment: Как вариант... Попробую...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подключение происходит на этапе заполнения данными `TableAdapter`. Метод `Fill`. Глубже нет смысла лезть. Это файл дизайнера вашего `DataSet`, который генерируется автоматически.